# Can someone do a CRSF attack on my youtube channel with my api key?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

So I am building a simple AJAX app that gets thumbnails from YouTube videos from my playlist that uses requests like this in the JavaScript:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?...&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But of course anyone who can view source can see my API key. YouTube says that API keys are not used for authorization, so theoretically there should be no reason not to include it in a client-side app. BUT YT API guide also says you can use the API key to do things like add videos to a playlist.

I have the REFERRER set to my own URL of course. But it seems it would not be too hard to fake a referrer on an xmlhttp request. By making my API public, am I making myself vulnerable to someone putting pron on my playlist or something?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with some research I can see that this is not really a danger. To do things like add videos to a playlist you need to log in with OAUTH2 client ID. As long as no one knows this ID (or better yet, if I don't even create one if I don't need it), then no one can do things like add and delete videos.